# Its showing only it's background componen,why not body component?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

when i press login ,it triggered this body file,but it only show background png. It's not showing content of body file.

background.dart

```
class Login_Background extends StatelessWidget {
  const Login_Background({required this.size, required Column child});

  final Size size;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Image.asset(
              "android/assets/images/login_top.png",
              width: size.width * .22,
            )),
        Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Image.asset(
              "android/assets/images/login_bottom.png",
              width: size.width * 0.31,
            )),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```

## body.dart

```
class body extends StatelessWidget {
  const body({
    Key? key,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;

    return Login_Background(
        size: size,
        child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Text(
                "login",
                style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
              ),
              SizedBox(height: size.height*0.03),
              Image.asset(
                "android/assets/images/12085707_20944201.jpg",
                height: 400,
                width: 100,
              ),
              RoundedInputField(
                hintText: 'Your Email',
                onChanged: (String value) {},
                icon: Icons.person,
              ),
              Rounded_password_field(
                onChanged: (String value) {},
              ),
              Roundedbutton(
                text: "login",
                press: () {},
                color: kPrimaryColor,
                textColor: kPrimaryColor,
              ),
              already_have_an_accountcheck(press: (){},)
            ]));
  }
}
```

i want to see body component when i hit login.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to add child to stack inside your Login_Background:

```
return Stack(
      children: [
        Positioned(
            top: 0,
            left: 0,
            child: Image.asset(
              "android/assets/images/login_top.png",
              width: size.width * .22,
            )),
        Positioned(
            bottom: 0,
            right: 0,
            child: Image.asset(
              "android/assets/images/login_bottom.png",
              width: size.width * 0.31,
            )),
        // add this
        Positioned.fill(                 
            child : child
        )

      ],
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

You have not used `child` param passed in constructor of Login_Background in its build method.